# Routing Issue between 2 Controllers on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

At the moment I have a website set up that has the following links as an example (these are development links): -

- http://www.example.com/help-advice/weird-and-wonderful-homes/purplebiz
- http://www.example.com/about-us/meet-the-team

Both of these work of the following routing.yml setup: -

```
singlepost:
    path:       /help-advice/{category}/{post}
    defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Posts:singlepost }

livepages:
    pattern:    /{slug}
    defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Pages:livepages }
    requirements:
        slug:   .+
```

Ideally, I would like to change the Help & Advice link to the following: -

- http://www.example.com/weird-and-wonderful-homes/purplebiz

Thus, having to change my routing.yml to : -

```
singlepost:
    path:       /{category}/{post}
    defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Posts:singlepost }

livepages:
    pattern:    /{slug}
    defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Pages:livepages }
    requirements:
        slug:   .+
```

As "/" are allowed in the livepages Controller this has caused an issue between the two controllers listed. If I visit the Meet the Team page, it tries to go back to the singlepost controller rather than the livepages controller.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Try swap this routes.

```
livepages:
    pattern:    /{slug}
    defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Pages:livepages }
    requirements:
        slug:   .+

singlepost:
    path:       /{category}/{post}
    defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Posts:singlepost }
```

**Updated**

This didn't work if / in slug is allowed.

Then, i think you can dynamically register routes using [Custom Route Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) for each category (or dynamically set list of allowed values (requirments) for existing one) with higher priority than livepages.

Or inversed solution: dynamically configure livepages route and set higher priority than singlepost

Comment: Hi Artur, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this didn't work as the Help and Advice post was working off the livepages controller rather than singlepost. This is because the livepages allows a "/" in the Slug.

Answer (score 1):

Define two routes with the same requirements and matching the same pattern doesn't make sense.
You need to make a difference between them (i.e. condition, requirements).

If you really need to keep it as actual, you can make some checks in the controller to make (or not) a redirection.

Example :

```
public function livepagesAction($slug) 
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $existingPage = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Page')->findBySlug($slug);

    if (!$existingPage) {
        $parsedUri = explode('/', $slug);

        // If no '/' or less than two route parameters, return a 404
        if (!strpos($slug, '/') || count($parsedUri) < 2) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Route not found');
        }

        // Redirect to the singlepost route 
        return $this->redirectToRoute('singlepost', array(
            'category' => $parsedUri[0],
            'post'     => $parsedUri[1],
        ));
    }

    // Render the view that corresponds to the existing slug.
}
```

In addition of some requirements in your `singlepost` route (such as specific type for params), you can adapt it to your need.

If that concerns more than two routes, you can lighten your controllers by creating an [EventListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-listener) that do it for you.