# Routing Issues in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm having a slight issue with Routing in my Symfony Application at the moment and I was just wondering if someone could help me out.

I have these two functions set up within my Controller in this exact order: -

```
/**
 * @Route("{region}/{area}", name="livearea")
 */
public function liveareaAction(Request $request, $region, $area)
{
    // START THE ENTITY MANAGER FOR DOCTRINE DB
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('crm');

    // FIND THE LOCATION REGION
    $query = $em->getRepository(ENTITY)->findOneBy(array('link' => $region));

    if($query == NULL || $query->getActive() == '0') {
        $slug = $region."/".$area;

        return $this->redirectToRoute("livepages", array('slug' => $slug));
    } else {
        // CONTINUE WITH CODE
    }
}
```

Then there is this one: -

```
/**
 * @Route("{slug}", name="livepages", requirements={"slug"=".+"})
 */
public function livepagesAction(Request $request, $slug)
{   
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Pages');
    $pages = $repository->findOneBySlug($slug);

    if($pages == NULL || $pages->getActive() == '0') {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Not Found');
    }

    // CONTINUE TO PAGE
}
```

Both are conflicting with one another. How I want it to work is if ***livearea*** doesn't have anything, then force the redirect to the ***livepages*** function. Is it possible for it to happen, and if so, how?

## UPDATE

This has been identified as a duplicate but the duplicate issue wasn't working. Therefore this has been raised as a new issue.

Comment: both are looking for variables. Try prefixing them with something.  E.g `@Route("region/{region}/{area}")` and `@Route("page/{slug}")`

Comment: Hi Rooneyl, unfortunately my guys don't want a prefix as these are used on a live site.

Comment: Try putting the livepagesAction first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing Issue between 2 Controllers on Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872531/routing-issue-between-2-controllers-on-symfony2)

Comment: I had tried this and it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working in a project with the exact same behaviour.

What I would do in your case is putting `livepagesAction` above `liveareaAction`, then adding a check in `livepages` if the `slug` matches the livearea Route with known Region and Area. If yes, forward to `livearea` with the given Region and Area.